# What method is called when application is awoken from background?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using cocos2d to develop a simple app. In this app, I want to display an ad every time the app is opened. I've been using didLoadFromCCB for everything, but I realized that method is not called every time the app is opened, only when it is opened after turning the phone off. I have also tried using

```
 -(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

but for some reason the app becomes slow and laggy after awaking it.

Is there any different method I can use?

Comment: Did you try `applicationWillEnterForeground:`

Comment: you should investigate the reasons.

Comment: @vikingosegundo honestly I'm not sure. The app isn't graphically intensive or demanding. It contains maybe 15 sprites. The main reason I suspected was because it has a timer that fires every 0.1 seconds, but I removed that timer for debug reasons and the app still lagged heavily upon awakening. I also commented out NSUserDefaults to see if that could be an issue but that didn't do anything either.

Comment: @Sen I just tried to implement it, but after awakening the app it seems to "freeze" and doesn't respond to anything.

Comment: Sounds as if you have a massive bug

Comment: @vikingosegundo  created a new project with only a button and a label. When the button is clicked, a "score" integer is updated by adding one to the previous number. The label then shows what the score is. It worked just fine without applicationDidBecomeActive, then when I implemented the method, it started to lag and become slow. More specifically, when I clicked the button it took a second or 2 to register. I am using cocos2d and Spritebuilder to build these apps. Hmmm..